# To make sub-domains as nameservers and use them as nameservers of another domain

Tags: domain-name-system

I own a domain (lets call it example.com) that is served by my own DNS server. (I asked my registrar to create glue records for ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com pointing to my server's IP address)

Now imagine that one of my friends get a new domain called new-domain.com and I want to help him manage his domain with my DNS server.

So in my DNS server, I created two A records as:

```
my1.ns.example.com -> some.ip.addr
```

and

```
my2.ns.example.com -> some.ip.addr
```

(some.ip.addr is the ip address of my DNS server)

and ask him to change his nameservers to

```
my.ns1.example.com
```

and

```
my.ns2.example.com
```

But he cannot set them because it gets invalid nameserver error in his domain panel!

We asked the support team of my friends's domain and they replied that those nameservers are not valid!

I contacted to my domain support and they said they've registered those names for me (I guess they created glue records!) and it started working.

Its my understanding that because example.com is working properly in DNS system and thus my1.ns.example.com and my2.ns.example.com are resolved to the IP address properly, so nothing can prevent them to be used as nameservers for new-domain.com

I searched around and found that some people say the nameservers should be registered. I understand registering when we have to ask for setting glue records, but for this case I have no idea why would we need to register those names.

Can someone explain what is happening in this scenario?

Update:

Here is the output of dig trace for a domain that is served by cloudflare.com dns system.

```
dig +trace +additional davat.info @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.10-Ubuntu <<>> +trace +additional davat.info @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
.           67120   IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           67120   IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           67120   IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           67120   IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           67120   IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           67120   IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           67120   IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           67120   IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           67120   IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           67120   IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           67120   IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           67120   IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           67120   IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           67120   IN  RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20170724170000 20170711160000 15768 . hOOzt9mqEniQLhLc+jNqChne/uMaCy0COI/3JObhMhpZWilJxm7g71q2 H4OIfgpxAdG77B/dsQbgPfScW7jemvKyZ+Jr72+Fuv0zQB5BoY0PQ9i/ JOoQQ9T6yqoxyMCV5+elx5KA8q95cFO1kQ0U7GwXnM5nGOE2M1Xs7cWh kdz05pErCoZ1I2V2+/DEHNrjOtpGtO/ysX0UBeKeWpGB88k2BLN/yLBN 2g8AkGlv6+S/cC+WuMHAAg25DxtrDm06jt5cwiQ+MNj6wOihZX+vRx41 AJU9SQg5vYY8P8KRtXn2sbzBrrqR/eJPWeWeouDUYQAomp6PUG3dsEjz /0iZZg==
;; Received 525 bytes from 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) in 9070 ms

info.           172800  IN  NS  a0.info.afilias-nst.info.
info.           172800  IN  NS  a2.info.afilias-nst.info.
info.           172800  IN  NS  b0.info.afilias-nst.org.
info.           172800  IN  NS  b2.info.afilias-nst.org.
info.           172800  IN  NS  c0.info.afilias-nst.info.
info.           172800  IN  NS  d0.info.afilias-nst.org.
info.           86400   IN  DS  8674 7 1 197789A2CBABA6FECD0B5AC88C5BC414CE1FC309
info.           86400   IN  DS  8674 7 2 EC9B6082B96B5F87143696F2B483ACC9B2C433DCE0C94E70F1FF5648 CA18008B
info.           86400   IN  RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20170727050000 20170714040000 15768 . RAOIKJ8CIq3gwj+WNN8pOdsNR+2KevOjFU22joZZORzuc3h30cIpi8jJ zFFRNVd0bXAzi9xPEZBhzy3o5MuDjPfeOtrROT8/SBTV64eoMoxJn31F myy0Aq5h1NLiw3LYJMGhQ/9JKXQc9PN/d0ifYer57rxtKvsS3PAtXwLu vP166UgoovFP7u37R6+Lr8vKpaRJu7P6RTP42Gzams6xnLkupsnnuFYt 6YcCJ4G2f9tDQLP4aaV2WtbKoNz79G9gyWdkwS5N1jGHDZRTVv+VlKER Mive01mOp+DfsqHLtanB7kLT2EOCOpO6ApREjVHcM6bM8bRK6pQn3FdM lh0Hdw==
a0.info.afilias-nst.info. 172800 IN A   199.254.31.1
a2.info.afilias-nst.info. 172800 IN A   199.249.113.1
b0.info.afilias-nst.org. 172800 IN  A   199.254.48.1
b2.info.afilias-nst.org. 172800 IN  A   199.249.121.1
c0.info.afilias-nst.info. 172800 IN A   199.254.49.1
d0.info.afilias-nst.org. 172800 IN  A   199.254.50.1
a0.info.afilias-nst.info. 172800 IN AAAA    2001:500:19::1
a2.info.afilias-nst.info. 172800 IN AAAA    2001:500:41::1
b0.info.afilias-nst.org. 172800 IN  AAAA    2001:500:1a::1
b2.info.afilias-nst.org. 172800 IN  AAAA    2001:500:49::1
c0.info.afilias-nst.info. 172800 IN AAAA    2001:500:1b::1
d0.info.afilias-nst.org. 172800 IN  AAAA    2001:500:1c::1
;; Received 813 bytes from 198.41.0.4#53(a.root-servers.net) in 2475 ms

davat.info.     86400   IN  NS  jobs.ns.cloudflare.com.
davat.info.     86400   IN  NS  nicole.ns.cloudflare.com.
adnsd9nk7nk82he8h21rj0jjhj11o5gb.info. 3600 IN NSEC3 1 1 1 D399EAAB ADOJ3MLQ5868PVF3LE0F5DCDGAVUTU55 NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
adnsd9nk7nk82he8h21rj0jjhj11o5gb.info. 3600 IN RRSIG NSEC3 7 2 3600 20170804103358 20170714093358 30893 info. FB7zcjFKGziJ457Vh/pIPkWqLguFe+rabdfJTa9McavqzOBGJIZTyhx/ icNVIyE4qBIJQ9xe7f1OmN5UHVe41nxBCWpH+JNQYHshWYKOIYCgdYE8 gHepP1ZR5AQ2Ev5lE0f/9+GBPlwxF47IKRQOYdFT51C2icm/SUvtdCG/ 4Ak=
2jefac1stko456rdlfe7g88kmtsvu2qs.info. 3600 IN NSEC3 1 1 1 D399EAAB 2JFPEQI6J2CMI8JU5V4Q0UTP6UDK9RQD NS DS RRSIG
2jefac1stko456rdlfe7g88kmtsvu2qs.info. 3600 IN RRSIG NSEC3 7 2 3600 20170730151955 20170709141955 30893 info. RQ4jTb4j7Dkp+M53zGqEiq3cyP6aCLqqIYyX9R9N4TXHHuBdw5XY78ma 9EDQt8I5NAiABKpImwy0HHudP8yVvaMhL/30ffHbt+naPWYTx9XVP/z9 xXkNtWAvATjf8Z9ntQOU/FBIOQHdfwg2HIv42PX+xvmsIMlx7HPmsyOW J4o=
;; Received 591 bytes from 199.249.113.1#53(a2.info.afilias-nst.info) in 983 ms

davat.info.     300 IN  A   82.102.11.201
;; Received 55 bytes from 173.245.58.211#53(nicole.ns.cloudflare.com) in 181 ms
```

For domain davat.info, two nameservers of cloudflare has been set.

```
jobs.ns.cloudflare.com.
nicole.ns.cloudflare.com.
```

I think if there were any glue records for those two nameservers, there were additional records after nameserver response.

```
davat.info.     86400   IN  NS  jobs.ns.cloudflare.com.
davat.info.     86400   IN  NS  nicole.ns.cloudflare.com.
```

But there is not!

If I enter these two nameservers of cloudflare in the domain control panel of mentioned new-domain.com domain, there will be no error!

So if it is true that for both jobs.ns.cloudflare.com and nicole.ns.cloudflare.com there are no glue records set, why would it works
for those names but not for my names in the domain control panel?

I need to know this because I need to be able to create dynamic nameservers programmatically and ask my users to enter their specific nameservers for their domains in their registrars.

Comment: Registrars for the newer TLDs (such as `.info`) tend to be more relaxed about requiring glue. As I mentioned in my answer, glue isn't *strictly* required for DNS to work in all cases at the TLD level, but if the web interface enforces the requirement you don't have a choice in the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its my understanding that because example.com is working properly in
>   DNS system and thus my1.ns.example.com and my2.ns.example.com are
>   resolved to the IP address properly, so nothing can prevent them to be
>   used as nameservers for new-domain.com
>
> I searched around and found that some people say the nameservers
>   should be registered. I understand registering when we have to ask for
>   setting glue records, but for this case I have no idea why would we
>   need to register those names.

The difference is where the glue lives. When you see an error about an invalid nameserver in a registrar control panel for an otherwise resolvable DNS entity, typically it is complaining about a missing glue record *at the registry level*. `com` cannot provide the glue for your friend's domain because the records are defined within `example.com`.

From a pure DNS perspective, an authoritative nameserver (such as those for `com`) *should not* perform any kind of recursion to learn the IP address of the nameservers that are defined in your `example.com` zone. Instead, the registry permits registrars to add glue records to the `com` domain, and those registrars can provide a user interface so that the owners of the domains that these custom nameservers live in can do so. (example: [Namecheap - How do I register personal nameservers for my domain?](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/768/10/how-do-i-register-personal-nameservers-for-my-domain))

(To address the elephant in the room...no, [these glue records are not strictly required](https://serverfault.com/a/785289/152073). But policies are policies, and if the registrar interface requires the registry level glue to be present, you have little choice in the matter.)

Comment: I updated my question, please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct.  I can only speculate that at the time your friend was updating his NS records to 'my.ns[12].example.com' they weren't resolvable yet. Hard to be certain after the fact.

Comment: Thank you @Brandon Xavier, I hardly believe that it is the case. Because I also tested it days after and still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your friend wants you to do his DNS for him, all he has to do is enter ns1/ns2.yourdomain.com for his name servers with his registrar.

You need to set up a zone file as appropriate for him, with A records, MX record(s), SPF/TXT records, etc.

If you want to delegate a subdomain to him, you need to do some things on your end, then some things on his end, and then he'll have a subdomain of yours with a working name server.  Note that I've not tested this subdomain name server as a NS entry in a domain registry for a 3rd domain,  but it should work.

First, on your domain, create the subdomain in the zone file.

```
$ORIGIN subdomain.example.com.
@       IN      NS      subdomain.example.com.
        IN      NS      ns1.example.com.

subdomain.example.com.    IN      A       10.2.3.4
```

And in `named.conf` or `named.conf.local` or where ever you are storing your "domains to service" info, specify that for that domain your nameservers will be slaves, and his server will be the master, replacing the `10.2.3.4` ip wtih the ip address of subdomain.example.com (your friends address).

```
zone "subdomain.example.com" {
        type slave;
        file "sec.example.com";
        masters { 10.2.3.4; };
};
```

Now, on his server in his `named.conf` or `named.conf.local` he needs to add an entry to service that domian, and allow your name servers to get domain transfers when he updates/sends notifications, replacing the `172.16.123.x` addresses wtih the ip addresses of ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com

```
zone "subdomain.example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/pri.subdomain.example.com";
        allow-transfer {172.16.123.231; 172.16.123.232;};
};
```

And then he creates his zone file as `/etc/bind/pri.subdomain.example.com` to look something like this -

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN     SOA   example.com. admin.example.com. (
               2017030707 ; serial number
               2h         ; refresh =  2 hours
               15M        ; update retry = 15 minutes
               3W12h      ; expiry = 3 weeks + 12 hours
               2h20M      ; minimum = 2 hours + 20 minutes
               )
; sub-domain name servers
                  IN      NS     subdomain.example.com.
                  IN      NS     ns1.example.com. ; see notes below
                  IN      NS     ns2.example.com. ; see notes below
; sub-domain mail server
                  IN      MX 10  mail.subdomain.example.com.

subdomain.example.com.  IN  A   10.2.3.4
ns1.example.com.        IN      A      172.16.123.231 ; 'glue' record
ns2.example.com.        IN      A      172.16.123.232 ; 'glue' record

; and then some other hosts in the subdomain
www     IN  A   10.2.3.4
mail    IN  A   10.2.3.7


subdomain.example.com. TXT  "v=spf1 a mx ptr ~all"
```

Now `subdomain.example.com` is an authorative name server, and create more hosts in its own zone, or it *should* be able to be a primary nameserver for some other zone.

Comment: Thank you @ivanivan. Of course he can always do that, but actually we want to test this particular scenario to see if A records in my domain can be nameservers in his domain without other special configs in registrar side.

Comment: Ah... I'll edit my answer to deal with that.

Comment: Thank you so much @ivanivan. Actually I don't want to delegate my sub-domain to him. We also suppose that he also does not own any dns server thus cannot create any zone.

Comment: Also It is not clear to me with this solution what nameservers he introduces to his registrar for his domain